# Proof in a tetrahedron - I added my wrong attempt

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

please help me solve this problem:

> There is a tetrahedron (ABCD), where $$
> > \angle{ACB}=\angle{ADB}=90^\circ $$ and $$ AC=CD=DB $$
>
> Prove, that $$ AB<2CD $$

**My (wrong) attempt:**

I marked
$$
|AC|=|CD|=|DB|=a
$$
$$
|AB|=c
$$
$$
|CB|=b
$$

I'm proving, that AB<2CD, so it means c<2a

Using Pythagoras' theorem":
$$
c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$$
so
$$
\sqrt{a^2+b^2}<2a
$$
and after transformation:
$$
b<\sqrt3a
$$
In order to prove, that AB<2CD, I need to prove
$$
b<\sqrt3*a
$$
In order to make CDB exist, it has to satisfy the following:
$$
a+b>a
$$
and
$$
a+a>b
$$
so:
$$
2a>b
$$

And now if 
$$b<2a
$$
and
$$
b<\sqrt3*a
$$
then b has to be less than sqrt3*a, because
$$
\sqrt{3}a<2a
$$

I proved, that
$$
b<\sqrt3a
$$
so
$$
c<2a
$$
so
$$
AB<2CD
$$

Best regards,
Adam.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible, because $AB$ is the hypotenuse of $\bigtriangleup ABC$, then $AB>AC=CD$.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to state that "In order to prove, that AB < 2CD, I need to prove $b < \sqrt3a$". Your proof is also correct about $b < 2a$. But you cannot prove $b < \sqrt3a$ simply because $b < 2a$.

For me, I can only prove $AB < \sqrt5CD$ as in the following:

$b < 2a$ 
=> $b^2 < 4a^2$ 
=> $a^2+b^2 < 5a^2$ 
=> $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} < \sqrt{5}a$ 
=> $c < \sqrt{5}a$.